# Regex detect any repeated character but with optional whitespace between

Tags: regex, regex-group

So currently I've got the following regex pattern, allowing me to detect any string containing 9 characters that are the same consecutively.

```
/^.*(\S)\1{9,}.*$/
```

This works perfectly with a string like the following: `this a tesssssssssst` however I wish for it to also detect a string like this: `this a tess sss ssssst` (Same number of the repeated character, but with optional whitespace)

Any ideas?

Comment: What if multiple spaces are between two `s`s?

Comment: @revo Yeah any amount of whitespace

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to put the backreference into a group and add an optional space into the group:

```
^.*(\S)(?: ?\1){9,}.*$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oVhjd2/1). If there can be more than 1 space in between, replace `?` with `*`.

The `.*$` part is only needed if you need to get the whole line match, for methods that allow partial matches, you may use `^.*(\S)(?: ?\1){9,}`.

If any whitespace is meant, replace the space with `\s` in the pattern.

Comment: Further question if you could: Detect any character combination repeated 9 or more time with spaces between?

Comment: Please provide sone example of real data and expected output.

Comment: Indeed, as the answer said @revo

Comment: @MattCowley: If you want to make a backreference not take into account whitespace, it is not possilbe. A backreference only refers to the value captured with the respective capturing group, and there is only a way to make it match in a case insensitive way. There is no "whitespace" insensitive modifier. You could match that with some hardcoded regex, like [this one](https://regex101.com/r/CfQzsd/1), but that is not what you want here.

Comment: I can't find a way to figure out why @Matt's [regex](http://regexr.com/3g6ua) matches in JS. I don't think it should.

Comment: Well, acc. to https://regex101.com/r/l9UtaN/1, there must be 2 matches. And that is as expected. But `this a tes t es  tes  tes  tes     tes  t es  tes  tes  tes t` cannot be matched with a pattern of this type.

Answer (score 0):

You can check more than a single character this way.
It's only limited by the number of capture groups available.

This one checks for 1 - 3 characters.

```
(\S)[ ]*(\S)?[ ]*(\S)?(?:[ ]*(?:\1[ ]*\2[ ]*\3)){9,}
```

http://regexr.com/3g709

```
 # 1-3 Characters
 ( \S )                        # (1)
 [ ]* 
 ( \S )?                       # (2)
 [ ]* 
 ( \S )?                       # (3)
 # Add more here

 (?:
      [ ]* 
      (?: \1 [ ]* \2 [ ]* \3 )
      # Add more here
 ){9,}
```